# Symfony 4.1, sonata Admin won't be overridden

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, overriding

I wanted to override editAction method of Sonata Admin.
I created an admin class and extended it from Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController
then I wrote editAction with my personal edit but when I access the edit post page, the old Sonata editAction gets called and not my function!
here is my admin class:

```
    <?php
namespace App\Controller;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController as Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use App\Manager\SiteManagerInterface;
use App\Manager\UserManagerInterface;
use App\Entity\Site;
use App\Entity\Profile;
use App\Entity\User;
use App\Entity\Payment;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class UserAdminCRUDController extends Controller
{
    /** @var SiteManagerInterface $siteManager */
    private $siteManager;


    public function editAction($id = null)
    {
        return new Response("test");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you forgot to register the action service. You can do it by: 
Either by using XML:

```
<!-- src/Resources/config/admin.xml -->

<service id="app.admin.car" class="App\Admin\CarAdmin">
    <tag name="sonata.admin" manager_type="orm" group="Demo" label="Car" />
    <argument />
    <argument>App\Entity\Car</argument>
    <argument>App\Controller\CRUDController</argument>
</service>
```

or in an yml

```
# src/Resources/config/admin.yml
services:
    app.admin.car:
        class: App\Admin\CarAdmin
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: Demo, label: Car }
        arguments:
            - null
            - App\Entity\Car
            - App\Controller\CRUDController
        public: true
```

You can read more about it [here](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/cookbook/recipe_custom_action.html)

Comment: I've already registered the action service, look
    `admin.user:
        class: App\Admin\UserAdmin
        arguments:
            - null
            - App\Entity\User
            - App\Controller\UserAdminCRUDController
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, label: User }
        public: true
        calls:
             - [init, ['@fos_user.user_manager', '@App\Manager\ProfileManagerInterface']]`
Or I shoudl also add service for the post too ?